# Statistical intepretation of ratio of spectral norm of covariance matrix to its Frobenius norm

Tags: mathematical-statistics, references, covariance-matrix

In statistics, given a covariance matrix $\Sigma$ with singular values $\sigma_1 \ge \sigma_2 \ge \ldots \ge \sigma_p$, is the ratio of its spectral norm to the Frobenius norm, i.e the ratio $\dfrac{\sigma_1}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^p \sigma_j^2}}$ of any interest ? That is, does this ratio appear naturally in the analysis of certain procedures, algorithms, convergence limits, etc. ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

It could be taken as an indicator of how close the matrix is to a rank 1 matrix. In MANOVA you have cases where this matters.

Comment: OK, thanks for mentioning MANOVA (never heard of that!). Any explicity reference of the how this ratio makes its way into MANOVA ? About low ranksity,  more generally, it's not hard to prove that $1 / rank(\Sigma) \le \sigma_1 / \|\Sigma\|_F \le 1$. For example, see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3638563/168758.

Comment: In 1-way MANOVA one wants to test equality of means when the response is multivariate. The statistics are functions of the eigenvalues of  $E^{-1}H$ where $H = n\sum_i(Y_{i.} - Y_{..})(Y_{i.} - Y_{..})^T$. Now, if the centroids of the groups are nearly aligned, a test statistic such as the Roy's maximum root will have better power than alternative statistics, such as Pillai's or Lawley-Hotelling.  Too long to explain in detail in a comment.

Comment: OK, great. Thanks! BTW, the comment could be made part of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one statistical interpretation of Frobenius norm of $\Sigma$.

Lets say that there's a dataset with $b$ rows $X$ whose empirical covariance matches $\Sigma$. We have

$$\|\Sigma\|^2_F=\|\frac{1}{b}X^TX\|_F^2=\frac{1}{b^2}\|XX^T\|_F^2$$

You can rewrite the last term as
$$\frac{1}{b^2}\sum_{ij} \langle x_i, x_j\rangle^2$$

In other words, $\|\Sigma\|^2_F$ is the average dot product between two pairs of examples in any representative dataset.

Meanwhile, spectral norm of $\Sigma$ is the largest variance among all directions, a kind of normalizing factor.

If we use trace instead of spectral norm, it gives us the quantity which occurs in linear estimation literature:

$$R=\frac{(\text{Tr}\Sigma)^2}{\text{Tr}\Sigma^2}$$

It's kind of a measure of degrees of freedom, giving the size of the largest batch such that samples are mostly pairwise uncorrelated.

When observations come from distributions with high value of $R$ the corresponding estimation problem is easy, for details, see definition 3 and Theorem 2 of [Uniform Convergence of Interpolators: Gaussian Width, Norm Bounds, and Benign Overfitting](https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.09276)